# Why are they called "minifigs"?

Tags: minifigures, history

Were larger-scale LEGO figures the standard at some point in the past? It just seems odd to me that they're called "mini" when they're basically the only kind of LEGO figures available (not counting vastly larger figures that are themselves models.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The minifigure is so-called because the original LEGO "Family" figures that were released in 1974 where somewhat larger, with bodies made from 2x2 Bricks, and arms made from hinged tubes.

[image: Original LEGO figure]

There's a bit more of a condensed history in the [minifigure tag wiki](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/tags/minifigures/info), and there is a bit more information about the minifigure as we know it today in the [Company Profile](http://aboutus.lego.com/en-us/lego-group/company-profile/)

Comment: It almost begs the question "Where are they now?".  I'm assuming the grandmother passed away.

Comment: @LarsTech There's a set of (most of) them up in my loft mixed in with the rest of my System LEGO bricks ;)

Comment: Dearly de-parted grandma. May she rest in pieces. ;-)

Comment: There are now also even smaller figures used in the board games. Nanofigs?

Comment: @Lunatik Those are called microfigures or Microfigs for short :)

Comment: The pieces used to make the arms have later been used in Classic Space sets. It can be seen [here](http://letsbuilditagain.com/instructions/6882/).

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the family figures, there was also the [1988 Technic action figures set (8712)](http://bricker.info/sets/8712/), which stood about 2.5 minifigs high from memory. There have been a few iterations over the years up into the 90's.

[image]