# When was the first official use of the term 'minifigure' or 'minifig'?

Tags: minifigures, lego-group

When did The LEGO Group first use the term minifigure? Have they been called that since their introduction in 1978?

Similar to this question: 
[Why are they called "minifigs"?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/why-are-they-called-minifigs)

Comment: "PEOPLE" in a 1979 brochure http://www.peeron.com/catalogs/1979/medium/12/?id=96

Answer (score 4):

I kept searching and found out for myself :). The US magazine from 1979 calls them Mini-Figures, even the version without arms.

http://www.peeron.com/catalogs/1979/medium/6/?id=97
http://www.peeron.com/catalogs/1979/medium/10/?id=97

Comment: Technically, this 1979 catalog use refers to Mini-Figure, which is slightly different to ‘Minifigure’ which the LEGO group would consider to be the official trademarked term.

Comment: Funny then, that the 1979 catalog as the TM trademark symbol right next to Mini-Figure ;)

Comment: If I knew how to freely search for trademarks to see when it was originally filed, I would, but AFAICT it costs $$$! :)